# How to define cusps of a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and holomorphicity of a modular form at these cusps.

Tags: modular-forms

I understand that when we define modular forms on a subgroup of the modular group we gain extra "boundary points" or cusps, on top of the point at $\infty$, where we require that said modular form is holomorphic. I am struggling to find a consistent definition for the cusps of such a subgroup, or for motivation for the extra holomorphicity condition at these cusps (what does it mean in practice). Anything that would help my understanding would be appreciated!

Comment: Any standard textbook on modular forms will cover this (e.g. there are excellent books by Diamond--Shurman, Kilford, Miyake, and Stein). I'm puzzled why you say there is a problem finding a "consistent" definition because there is AFAIK complete consistency between the standard texts, they all give exactly the same definition. (You should understand "holomorphic at the cusps" as intuitively meaning "doesn't blow up as you go towards the boundary of the upper half-plane".)